# How to implement outline variant using tailwind and class-variance-authority

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a customizable library with different types of buttons. I'm using cva (class-variance-authority) to implement the variants. Currently having trouble trying to define the outline variant, I would like the button to change, on hover, from a transparent background to the background color specified in colors, similar to bootstrap. Is there a proper way to do it? I'm a newbie just getting started with tailwindcss.

Here is the code of variants.ts that implements the different buttons.

```
import { cva } from "class-variance-authority";

/**
 * Button styles for the Button component.
 */
export const buttonStyles = cva(
    "flex flex-row gap-x-4 disabled:cursor-not-allowed items-center justify-center",
    {
        variants: {
            buttonType: {
                primary: "hover:bg-opacity-75",
                outline: "bg-transparent", // outline variant
                warning: "border-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-600",
                disabled: "bg-black text-white border-black cursor-not-allowed",
                error: "bg-red-500 text-white border-red-500 hover:bg-red-600",
            },
            color: {
                default: ["text-white", "bg-black", "border-black"],
                black: ["text-white", "bg-black", "border-black"],
                white: ["text-black", "bg-white", "border-white"],
                gray: ["text-gray-500", "bg-gray-200", "border-gray-500"],
                red: ["text-red-500", "bg-red-200", "border-red-500"],
                yellow: ["text-yellow-500", "bg-yellow-200", "border-yellow-500"],
                green: ["text-green-500", "bg-green-200", "border-green-500"],
                blue: ["text-blue-500", "bg-blue-200", "border-blue-500"],
                indigo: ["text-indigo-500", "bg-indigo-200", "border-indigo-500"],
                purple: ["text-purple-500", "bg-purple-200", "border-purple-200"],
                pink: ["text-pink-500", "bg-pink-200", "border-pink-200"],
                teal: ["text-teal-500", "bg-teal-200", "border-teal-200"],
                orange: ["text-orange-500", "bg-orange-200", "border-orange-500"],
            },
            size: {
                default: ["text-base"],
                small: ["text-sm"],
                large: ["text-lg"],
                xxl: ["text-2xl"],
            },
            spacing: {
                default: ["py-2", "px-4"],
                small: ["py-1", "px-2"],
                large: ["py-3", "px-6"],
                xxl: ["py-4", "px-8"],
            },
            rounded: {
                default: "rounded-md",
                sm: "rounded-sm",
                lg: "rounded-lg",
                xl: "rounded-xl",
                xxl: "rounded-2xl",
                none: "rounded-none",
                full: "rounded-full",
            },
        },
        compoundVariants: [
            {
                buttonType: "primary",
                size: "default",
                color: "default",
                spacing: "default",
                rounded: "default",
            },
        ],
        defaultVariants: {
            buttonType: "primary",
            size: "default",
            color: "default",
            rounded: "default",
            spacing: "default",
        },
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting a CSS variable for each of the colors. You could then use this CSS variable as a value for the `background-color` on hover:

```js
/**
 * Button styles for the Button component.
 */
const buttonStyles = cva(
  "flex flex-row gap-x-4 disabled:cursor-not-allowed items-center justify-center",
  {
    variants: {
      buttonType: {
        primary: "hover:bg-opacity-75",
        outline: "bg-transparent hover:bg-[--color]",
        warning: "border-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-600",
        disabled: "bg-black text-white border-black cursor-not-allowed",
        error: "bg-red-500 text-white border-red-500 hover:bg-red-600",
      },
      color: {
        default: ["text-white", "bg-black", "border-black", "[--color:theme(colors.black)]"],
        black: ["text-white", "bg-black", "border-black", "[--color:theme(colors.black)]"],
        white: ["text-black", "bg-white", "border-white", "[--color:theme(colors.white)]"],
        gray: ["text-gray-500", "bg-gray-200", "border-gray-500", "[--color:theme(colors.gray.500)]"],
        red: ["text-red-500", "bg-red-200", "border-red-500", "[--color:theme(colors.red.500)]"],
        yellow: ["text-yellow-500", "bg-yellow-200", "border-yellow-500", "[--color:theme(colors.yellow.500)]"],
        green: ["text-green-500", "bg-green-200", "border-green-500", "[--color:theme(colors.green.500)]"],
        blue: ["text-blue-500", "bg-blue-200", "border-blue-500", "[--color:theme(colors.blue.500)]"],
        indigo: ["text-indigo-500", "bg-indigo-200", "border-indigo-500", "[--color:theme(colors.indigo.500)]"],
        purple: ["text-purple-500", "bg-purple-200", "border-purple-200", "[--color:theme(colors.purple.500)]"],
        pink: ["text-pink-500", "bg-pink-200", "border-pink-200", "[--color:theme(colors.pink.500)]"],
        teal: ["text-teal-500", "bg-teal-200", "border-teal-200", "[--color:theme(colors.teal.500)]"],
        orange: ["text-orange-500", "bg-orange-200", "border-orange-500", "[--color:theme(colors.orange.500)]"],
      },
      size: {
        default: ["text-base"],
        small: ["text-sm"],
        large: ["text-lg"],
        xxl: ["text-2xl"],
      },
      spacing: {
        default: ["py-2", "px-4"],
        small: ["py-1", "px-2"],
        large: ["py-3", "px-6"],
        xxl: ["py-4", "px-8"],
      },
      rounded: {
        default: "rounded-md",
        sm: "rounded-sm",
        lg: "rounded-lg",
        xl: "rounded-xl",
        xxl: "rounded-2xl",
        none: "rounded-none",
        full: "rounded-full",
      },
    },
    compoundVariants: [
      {
        buttonType: "primary",
        size: "default",
        color: "default",
        spacing: "default",
        rounded: "default",
      },
    ],
    defaultVariants: {
      buttonType: "primary",
      size: "default",
      color: "default",
      rounded: "default",
      spacing: "default",
    },
  },
);

button1.className = buttonStyles({ color: 'red' });
button2.className = buttonStyles({ buttonType: 'outline', color: 'red' });
button3.className = buttonStyles({ color: 'green' });
button4.className = buttonStyles({ buttonType: 'outline', color: 'green' });
button5.className = buttonStyles({ color: 'blue' });
button6.className = buttonStyles({ buttonType: 'outline', color: 'blue' });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/clsx@2.0.0/dist/clsx.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.require = () => window.clsx;
window.exports = {}
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/class-variance-authority@0.7.0/dist/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<button id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3">Button 3</button>
<button id="button4">Button 4</button>
<button id="button5">Button 5</button>
<button id="button6">Button 6</button>
```

You could possibly extrapolate this abstraction further for the other `buttonType` variants too.